# Does this copy the vector?

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, reference

If I have the following code, is the vector copied?

```
std::vector<int> x = y.getTheVector();
```

or would it depend on whether the return type of `getTheVector()` is by reference?

or would I just need to use:

```
std::vector<int>& x = y.getTheVector();
```

or, would I need to do both?

Comment: If `x` is a reference it is not copied, if it isnt , it is.

Comment: I disagree with awesomeyi.  The return of the getTheVector function is irrelevant; it's what you're assigning to that matters.

Comment: Okay, I do agree with @awesomeyi's edited answer, which is that it depends on the type of x, not the return type of the `getTheVector` function.

Comment: If `getTheVector` returns anything but a reference to something that's not temporary, you have a big problem with the second line.

Comment: This is extremely interesting guys- so the function return type doesn't determine the passing mechanism? Its the type of the object on the caller side (in this case whether x is a reference or not)!?

Comment: Well, it's what's on the left-hand side that matters in this case.  (I wouldn't necessarily refer to it as the "caller" side, though, as a single line/statement of C++ code can have multiple function calls.)  
Basically, any time you are assigning to a C++ object, in the same statement that declares the object, as in your first example, you're invoking a copy constructor.  But in your second example, you're not assigning to a C++ object; you're actually assigning to a reference (which is somewhat similar to assigning to a pointer in this regard).

Comment: @user997112 no, the function return type does determine the passing mechanism. You seem to be mixing up the passing mechanism with what is being done with the value once returning has finished.  Conceptually, the return value is generated and returned; (if this is an object then it's a temporary one, otherwise it's a reference). Then we do something with the return value (e.g. copy-construct `x` from it, or bind ref `x` to it) which is entirely a separate operation.

Comment: Matt is correct, although I'm also correct, just about something different.  If you remove all the code up to and including the equal sign on either line, something is still being returned from the call to `y.getTheVector()`. If that function returns a vector, then simply calling the function could be copying from an original vector belonging to the object y, and that vector would in turn be copied again by assigning it to x on the first line. On the other hand, if the function returns a reference, then that reference will still be copied in your first example, but not in your second example.

Comment: Although, the utility of a function which returns a reference is questionable.  I think it's better in most cases to return a pointer, and you can decide whether the returned pointer (and the function itself) should be const, i.e., read-only to the caller, or non-const, to allow the caller to modify whatever is pointed to.  I personally mainly use references as function parameters, often const references, not as return types.

Comment: The one notable exception to my "functions shouldn't return references" advice is operator functions.  Typically, an assignment operator function will return a reference to `*this` to allow assignment chaining, and in string classes, the += (concatenation) operator will often return a reference as well, to allow chaining of  concatenation (e.g. `std::string a = b + c + d`).

Comment: Just got one related Q, if I made a vector data member (myvector) public, would std::vector<int> x = y.myvector invoke a copy?

Comment: Yes, whether you assign to a vector that's retrieved as a member of an object, or assign to a vector that's returned from a function, the assignment is the same, and will invoke a copy.

Answer (score 6):

```
std::vector<int> x = y.getTheVector();
```

always makes a copy, regardless of the return type of `y.getTheVector();`.

```
std::vector<int>& x = y.getTheVector();
```

would not make a copy. However, `x` will be valid as long as `y.getTheVector()` returns a reference to an object that is going to be valid after the function returns. If `y.getTheVector()` returns an object created in the function, `x` will point to an object that is no longer valid after the statement.

Comment: In C++11, the first line would cause a move in stead of a copy, unless the return type is a reference.

Comment: @Aberrant The compiler will elide the copy. It won't even do a move.

Comment: @Aberrant, also [return value optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization) is not a C++11 invention, although any C++11 compiler could be expected to perform RVO. And there may be situations where the compiler can't perform the optimization.

Answer (score 2):

```
std::vector<int> x = y.getTheVector();
```

This is copy-initialization. There are three possible scenarios:

1. The return value of `getTheVector()` is a lvalue reference. In this case, the copy constructor is always invoked.
2. The return value of `getTheVector()` is a temporary. In this case, the move constructor may be called, or the move/copy may be completely elided by the compiler.
3. The return value is a rvalue reference (usually a terrible idea). In this case, the move constructor is called.

For this line,

```
 std::vector<int>& x = y.getTheVector();
```

This only compiles if `getTheVector` returns a lvalue reference; a temporary cannot be bound a non-const lvalue reference. In this case, no copy is ever made; but the lifetime problem may be tricky.

Answer (score 1):

```
std::vector<int> x = y.getTheVector();
```

Your first example does indeed copy the vector, regardless of whether the "getTheVector" function returns a vector or a reference to a vector.

```
std::vector<int>& x = y.getTheVector();
```

In your second example, however, you are creating a reference, so the vector will NOT be copied.